# in hadoop cat, | head doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, cat

Hi I have a csv file in HDFS, I'd like to take a look.

These two commands works:

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://192.168.200.121:8020/python/DI.csv
hadoop fs -tail hdfs://192.168.200.121:8020/python/DI.csv
```

but

```
hadoop fs -tail hdfs://192.168.200.121:8020/python/DI.csv | head
```

doesn't work w/ an error:

> 'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Anybody knows why? Thank you-

Comment: What operating system are you on? Can you do a `head some-file-on-local-disk.txt` and get results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords... **or batch file**.

You are on Windows, where `head` is not a command. The closest you might be able to get is [with PowerShell](https://serverfault.com/a/490842)

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://192.168.200.121:8020/python/DI.csv | Select -First 20
```

However, it would be more useful to use something like Pig or Hive to run a SELECT + LIMIT query over the CSV

Answer (score -1):

Because tail will show data from the end and head will display data from the top.

Comment: Thank you @Kavita.    | head throws an error. See update in OP